# vk:comments для разных страниц?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вконтакте

Есть сайт - site.com, в котором папки 01, 02, 03, 04 и т.п

Для этого сайта подключил виджет для комментариев

https://vk.com/dev/Comments

Получил следующий код:

```
<!-- Put this script tag to the <head> of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?116"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         VK.init({apiId: здесь полученное id , onlyWidgets: true});
    </script>

<div id="vk_comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 20, width: "", attach: "*"});
</script>
```

Устанавливаю данный код для страниц 01, 02, 03, 04 и т.п - но почему то комментариии разные, т.е если пользователь создал коммент на странице 01 - этот коммент не отображается на остальных страницах. 
Как связать комментарии, чтобы комменты отображались на всех страницах одинаково.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, нужно указывать параметр `page_id` одинаковым для всех страниц.

https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments

> page_id — идентификатор страницы на Вашем сайте. Произвольное число. Используется в том случае, если у одной и той же статьи может быть несколько адресов, а также на динамических сайтах, у которых меняется только хеш. **Значение по умолчанию равно контрольной сумме от location.href**.

Comment: Спасибо. Решил проблему указав pageUrl: "http://site.ru"